# jQuery: "hyphens: none;" for words from a text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `hyphens: auto;` for my web page. But there are some words that I wouldn't like to wrap. And these words are very often on my website.

Is it possible to create a *.txt* file, take the words from this file, and add especially for those a `span` with a `class` via jQuery?

Idea:

```js
$.get('txt-file.txt', function(data) {
  $("data").replaceWith("<span class='no-hyphens'>'data'</span>");
}, 'text');
```

```css
p {
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.no-hyphens {
  -webkit-hyphens: none;
  -ms-hyphens: none;
  hyphens: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Dorothy lived in the midst of the great Kansas prairies, with Uncle Henry, who was a farmer, and Aunt Em, who was the farmer's wife. Their house was small, for the lumber to build it had to be carried by wagon many miles. There were four walls, a floor
  and a roof, which made one room; and this room contained a rusty looking cookstove, a cupboard for the dishes, a table, three or four chairs, and the beds. Uncle Henry and Aunt Em had a big bed in one corner, and Dorothy a little bed in another corner.
  There was no garret at all, and no cellar except a small hole dug in the ground, called a cyclone cellar, where the family could go in case one of those great whirlwinds arose, mighty enough to crush any building in its path.</p>



<code id="txt-file">
"prairies", "whirlwinds", "contained", "building"
</code>
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a text file? How do you define the words of your texts which should put into `span`s?

Comment: I only would like to mark this words in a text file. Doing it in the HTML file would be very much work ...

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't see exactly what the problem is here. Do you want to create a text file? Because that is not possible with jQuery. Here is already a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205676/how-can-i-create-a-txt-file-using-jquery

Comment: No, I want to create this text file by myself. And insert some words that I didn't want to wrap. And jQuery should read this word and add for those a class.